# Не обновляется datagridview при очистке базы данных sql

Tags: c#, winforms

Излазил уже просторы интернета, но до сих пор не понял как правильно обновить datagridview 
Что делаю не так?

```
parserDataSet.Table_parser.Clear();
 table_parserDataGridView.DataSource = null;
 MessageBox.Show("Данные очищены");
 table_parserTableAdapter.Fill(parserDataSet.Table_parser);
 table_parserDataGridView.DataSource = parserDataSet.Table_parser;
```

Comment: table_parserDataGridView.Refresh(); пробовали после повторной привязки данных?

Comment: да пробовал. Результат тот же!

Comment: Такое ощущение что в dataset адаптер подгружает не очищенную базу данных а старую ее копию

Comment: А вы проверьте, очистилась она или нет, перед загрузкой.

Comment: О, б̶о̶г̶и̶  модераторы! Дайте мне возможность минусовать тех, кто не к месту лепит вызов `Control.Refresh`! PS: этот метод вызывает _перерисовку_ компонента (вызывает OnPaint), но никак не связан с привязкой данных. @avocado03